# Status Error and blank status page

Tags: drupal, error, admin, angular, bower

On our CiviCRM deployment, running 4.7.23, it says System Status: Error in the footer. When clicking the System Status: Error link, I get a blank page with the following console errors (url redacted):

```
GET https://<redacted_base_url>/[civicrm.files]persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.2513685c7e9bf04c4c187f640cffc720.js 

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.11%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DcrmApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A6%3A426%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A25%3A235%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A24%3A282)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A25%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A40%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A7%3A371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A39%3A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(https%3A%2F%2<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A43%3A381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A21%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Gc%20(https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fsites%2Fall%2Fmodules%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fovlk9u%3A21%3A332)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4692
at q (angular.js:325)
at g (angular.js:4653)
at fb (angular.js:4575)
at c (angular.js:1809)
at Gc (angular.js:1830)
at se (angular.js:1715)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:32616)
at i (jquery.min.js?ovlk9u:2)
```

```

My [civicrm.files] variable seems correct:

```
[civicrm.files] /var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm
```

The contents of `/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm` are:

```
# pwd
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files

# ls -la civicrm/
total 44
drwxr--r--  8 www-data www-data  4096 helmi  5  2016 .
drwxrwxrwx 26 www-data www-data  4096 kesä   8 03:38 ..
drwxr-----  2 www-data www-data  4096 syys   1 04:14 ConfigAndLog
drwxr--r--  2 www-data www-data  4096 syys   6 04:27 custom
drwxr--r--  3 www-data www-data  4096 syys   6 04:27 ext
drwxr--r--  3 www-data www-data  4096 joulu 21  2016 persist
drwxr--r--  3 www-data www-data  4096 syys   6 04:24 templates_c
drwxr--r--  3 www-data www-data 16384 syys   6 04:27 upload
```

How should I configure the [civicrm.files], so that it can serve the Bower components properly?

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this issue on a site I was working on.  Hopefully it helps you as well.  My issue was directory permissions.  You need to make sure that all of your directories have permissions set to **755**.  My contribute folder was set to 750, which did not allow the directory structure to be loaded beyond that point.  Because of that, it's not able to load the **angular-modules.2513685c7e9bf04c4c187f640cffc720.js** file.

An easy way to do this is to use FileZilla and navigate to somewhere you know is ok, maybe your /var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/ directory.  Then you can right-click on the **files** folder and choose File Attributes or File Permissions depending on which pane you use, and make sure permissions are set to 755.  Now choose **Recurese into subdirectories** and **MAKE SURE** you select **Apply to directories only**, you don't want to apply it to files.  Click OK and once it completes, try going to your system status page again and hopefully it works now!

[image]

Comment: See also (for command line permissions changes): https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/22940/26

Comment: I had this issue, but for a different reason - i had changed the site hostname previously, but some .js files served from the old domain, triggering a CORS error, due to missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: header. After fixing that, i could view the screens.

Comment: Or just edit CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in civicrm.settings.php