# CiviMail Reports is not tracking email opens

Tags: civimail, civireport, tracked-links

I am using civi 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.4

I noticed that civimail reports is not tracking the email opens after multiple sends.  It is just showing "0". In the screen shot, you can see where it is showing click-throughs but not opens.
[image]

The checkboxes for tracking opens and click-through are set.
[image]

In the email source, I found this URL  https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/open.php?q=66

That URL takes me to 404 Error Page.

The permission are:

open.php 755

civicrm/civicrm/extern/ 777

civicrm/civicrm/ 755

civicrm/  755

Does anything look wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like cms is blocking you. Check wp permissions for mailing

Comment: Where do you check wp permissions for mailing?

Comment: I have no clue try somewhere like Administer > Users and Permissions > Permissions > Access Control

Comment: I am not seeing any permissions that appear to be related to this in there.  Did you have to check permissions for your install?

Comment: I don't have a wp installation so I am unable to check. Basically what I think is happening with your installation is that CMS in your case wp is blocking access to that open.php, try looking at your htaccess and find the rule which is preventing the php file from being read.

Comment: this is all that is in my htaccess: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced something similar on a few sites and it turns out the file/directory permissions are not set right. I'm not sure what causes it, but I have found that I need to recursively reset permissions after updating CiviCRM, or the tracking doesn't work, click through links don't work, you can't upload images from CiviMail, etc.

From just outside the `civicrm` directory, I do this and it seems to solve it:

```
find civicrm -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ";"

find civicrm -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ";"
```

The first one changes permissions on directories and the second on files. You want to avoid having anything set to `777` for sure.

Comment: I am thrilled. Changing those permissions not only solved the tracking issue instantly, but also fixed some other annoying little issues i had been noticing.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @laryn-cedc-org Thank you for this hopeful instruction. Could you explain exactly where in the file structure "From just outside the civicrm directory" is?

Comment: When you upgrade civicrm, you have to replace the entire `civicrm` directory with the upgraded files. If you are one step above that directory (e.g. on Backdrop CiviCRM core files are at `[website]/modules/civicrm`. In that case you'd be in the `[website]/modules/` directory to run these commands.) Does that help?

Comment: I'll take a look at this suggested fix, given that I've just noticed that on one of my sites trackable links have just started generating 404 errors, although I'm sure everything was fine as recently as 2 months ago. now on Civi version 5.31