# Some links are thowing 403 error

Tags: wordpress, permissions

Survey creation is throwing "403 error - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource"

I am experiencing same error on multiple links of CiviCRM. 
I am using CiviCRM4.7 on wordpress.

Comment: You might check permissions on the civicrm folder -- see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22881/civimail-reports-is-not-tracking-email-opens/22940#22940